# Contar cuantas filas hay arriba de una preseleccionada php

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html5, base-de-datos

¡Hola! Dare primero mi pregunta y luego la base de datos y pruebas que hice:

Tengo una tabla que tiene un atributo llamado "victorias" mediante este, selecciono en una especie de "Top" a los usuarios con mas victorias, en el perfil de estos usuarios, se muestra la posicion con respecto a los demas usuarios, por ejemplo:

Usuario 1 tiene 8 victorias, usuario 2 tiene 4 y usuario 3 tiene 11.

En este caso, se mostrarian de esta manera (si hago un while con un order by):

- Usuario 3
- Usuario 1
- Usuario 2

Mi pregunta es, como puedo tomar la posicion de este usuario 1 (como ejemplo) y mostrarla en el perfil como:

Usuario 1

posicion: 2

Mi base de datos es:

- id
- nombre
- posicion
- victorias
- jugados

Lo ideal seria tomar una media entre victorias y jugados, de tal manera que se cree una especie de "Porcentaje de victorias" y que quienes tienen mas, se muestran mas arriba, pero como se que esto es algo mas complejo, lo dejo como algo secundario que pueden o no responder, lo importante es poder tomar la posicion con respecto a los demas.

Ya logre hacer un `"SELECT * FROM usuarios ORDER BY victorias DESC"` pero no se si esto sirve para lo que quiero hacer, no avance nada, siento no poder dar mas codigo, si necesitan algo, haganmelo saber.

¡Gracias por la ayuda que puedan brindarme!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realmente es muy fácil, solo necesitas contar la cantidad de usuarios (incluyendo el actual) que tengan misma o mayor cantidad de victorias:

```
// ID de usuario y sus victorias
// Debes tomarlo de la consulta donde lees el usuario actual
$usuario = 5;    // $row['id']?
$victorias = 20; // $row['victorias']?

// Simplemente lo agregas como filtro a la consulta
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) as posicion FROM usuarios
    WHERE victorias >= $victorias
    ORDER BY victorias DESC";
// Ejecutas la consulta y posteriormente lees con
$posicion = $row['posicion'];
```

El único problema con esto es que si hay dos o más usuarios con la misma cantidad de victorias van a compartir la misma posición y podría ser conveniente involucrar otros factores para obtener un resultado más adecuado, probablemente con agregar `partidas ASC` en el orden sea buena idea.

Comment: Ohhh genial muchisimas gracias, no se porque no se me ocurrio jaja

Comment: Edite tu respuesta porque pusiste que seleccione donde "id = '$id' y eso hacia que solo me seleccione a un equipo, sin embargo, super util tu respuesta :D